# how to focus and scroll textfield of bottom position using focusRequest in LazyColumn when i click the button automatically?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

how to show textfield using focusRequester in lazycolumn?

The screen is composed of Lazycholumn, and the list part shown at the bottom of the capture picture shows the lists using LazyListScope. The boolean value shows the textfield, which is shown at the bottom of the lists shown by LazyListScope. There is no error when there is no LazyListScope or there is a space at the bottom, but this error occurs when the screen at the bottom is full with LazyListScope

when i try to apply this, i have a issue

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.todo_android, PID: 8769
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
       FocusRequester is not initialized. Here are some possible fixes:
    
       1. Remember the FocusRequester: val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
       2. Did you forget to add a Modifier.focusRequester() ?
       3. Are you attempting to request focus during composition? Focus requests should be made in
       response to some event. Eg Modifier.clickable { focusRequester.requestFocus() }
    
        at androidx.compose.ui.focus.FocusRequester.focus$ui_release(FocusRequester.kt:218)
        at androidx.compose.ui.focus.FocusRequester.requestFocus(FocusRequester.kt:63)
        at com.example.todo_android.screen.CalendarScreenKt$CalendarScreen$2$1.invokeSuspend(CalendarScreen.kt:244)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performTrampolineDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:81)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performTrampolineDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:41)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.run(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:57)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
       Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [androidx.compose.ui.platform.MotionDurationScaleImpl@5912b30, androidx.compose.runtime.BroadcastFrameClock@11833a9, StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@4c1ad2e, AndroidUiDispatcher@8cef0cf]
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8769 SIG: 9
```

i did those, that is :

```
1. val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
2. Modifier.focusRequester()
3. Modifier.clickable { focusRequester.requestFocus() }
```

and this is my code
(Except for LazyListScope, I selected only the parts with TextField and brought them.)

```
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(Color(0xfff0f0f0)),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
    state = rememberLazyListState()
) {
    item {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .shadow(
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(bottomStart = 30.dp, bottomEnd = 30.dp),
                        elevation = 7.dp,
                        spotColor = Color(0xffB0B0B0),
                        ambientColor = Color(0xffB0B0B0)
                    ),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
            ) {
                CalendarTitle(yearMonth = selectedDate.yearMonth)

                CalendarHeader(daysOfWeek = daysOfWeek)

                CalendarContent(
                    selectedDate = selectedDate,
                    weekState = weekState,
                    monthState = monthState,
                    isMonthMode = animateState.value,
                    onSelectedDate = {

                        selectedDate = it

                        val dayOfWeek =
                            LocalDate.of(it.year, it.monthValue, it.dayOfMonth).dayOfWeek

                        dayString = when (dayOfWeek.value) {
                            1 -> "월요일"
                            2 -> "화요일"
                            3 -> "수요일"
                            4 -> "목요일"
                            5 -> "금요일"
                            6 -> "토요일"
                            7 -> "일요일"
                            else -> null.toString()
                        }
                        scope.launch {
                            vm.readTodo(token, it.year, it.monthValue, it.dayOfMonth)
                        }
                    }
                )
            }

            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(start = 21.dp, end = 21.dp, top = 30.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = if (
                        selectedDate.dayOfMonth.toString().length == 1
                    ) {
                        "0${selectedDate.dayOfMonth}"
                    } else {
                        "${selectedDate.dayOfMonth}"
                    },
                    fontSize = 26.sp,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 6.dp)
                )

                Text(
                    fontSize = 14.sp,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium,
                    lineHeight = 18.sp,
                    color = Color(0xff9E9E9E),
                    text = dayString
                )

                Divider(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(start = 6.dp, top = 1.dp),
                    color = Color(0xffdddbdb)
                )
            }
        }
    }

    TodoItem(
        vm = vm,
        token = token,
        categoryList = categoryList,
        categoryTodoList = categoryTodoList,
        scope = scope
    )

    item {
        LaunchedEffect(isVisibility) {
            if (isVisibility) {
                focusRequester.requestFocus()
            }
        }

        if (isVisibility) {
            Card(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(45.dp)
                    .padding(start = 21.dp, end = 21.dp),
                colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(Color.White),
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
            ) {
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(
                            start = 12.dp,
                            top = 13.dp,
                            bottom = 13.dp
                        ),
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
                ) {
                    Image(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.blankcheckbox),
                        contentDescription = null
                    )

                    BasicTextField(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .wrapContentWidth()
                            .wrapContentHeight()
                            .padding(start = 16.dp)
                            .imePadding(),
                        value = todoTitle,
                        onValueChange = { text ->
                            vm.setTodoTitle(text)
                        },
                        textStyle = androidx.compose.material3.LocalTextStyle.current.copy(
                            fontSize = 13.sp,
                            fontStyle = FontStyle.Normal,
                            color = Color.Black,
                            lineHeight = 31.sp
                        ),
                        singleLine = true,
                        maxLines = 1,
                        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                            keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
                            imeAction = ImeAction.Done
                        ),
                        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = {
                            scope.launch {
                                vm.createTodo(
                                    token,
                                    CreateTodo(
                                        todoYear,
                                        todoMonth,
                                        todoDay,
                                        todoTitle,
                                        todoColor
                                    )
                                )
                                vm.setTodoTitle("")
                                isVisibility = !isVisibility
                            }
                        })
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        if (todoList.isEmpty() && !isVisibility) {
            Row {
                BlankTodoItem()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is a FAB and Card Composable for that is changing valuable(isVisiblity) and showing textfield

```
@Composable
fun AddTodoFloatingButton(
    multiFloatingState: FloatingStateType,
    onMultiFloatingStateChange: (FloatingStateType) -> Unit,
    backgroundColor: Color,
    onButtonClick: (String) -> Unit,
    focusRequester: FocusRequester,
) {
    val transition = updateTransition(targetState = multiFloatingState, label = null)

    val rotate by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = if (multiFloatingState == FloatingStateType.Expanded) 45f else 0f,
        animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 400) // 여기서 애니메이션 지속 시간을 설정할 수 있습니다.
    )

    val NextButtonArrowTint = when (multiFloatingState) {
        FloatingStateType.Expanded -> {
            Color(0xFFFFFFFF).copy(alpha = 1f)
        }
        FloatingStateType.Collapsed -> {
            Color(0xFF424242).copy(alpha = 1f)
        }
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(
            end = 20.dp,
            bottom = 150.dp
        ),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End
    ) {

        AnimatedVisibility(
            visible = (multiFloatingState == FloatingStateType.Expanded),
            enter = fadeIn(
                animationSpec = tween(500)
            ) + slideInVertically(
                animationSpec = tween(500),
                initialOffsetY = {
                    it / 8
                }
            ),
            exit = fadeOut(
                animationSpec = tween(500)
            ) + slideOutVertically(
                animationSpec = tween(500),
                targetOffsetY = {
                    it / 8
                }
            )
        ) {
            FloatingActionButtonMenus(
                onMultiFloatingStateChange,
                onButtonClick,
                focusRequester
            )
        }

        FloatingActionButton(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(bottom = 18.dp)
                .size(65.dp)
                .shadow(
                    elevation = 4.dp,
                    shape = CircleShape,
                    spotColor = Color(0xff9E9E9E),
                    ambientColor = Color(0xffACACAC)
                ),
            containerColor = backgroundColor,
            shape = CircleShape,
            onClick = {
                onMultiFloatingStateChange(
                    if (transition.currentState == FloatingStateType.Expanded) {
                        FloatingStateType.Collapsed
                    } else {
                        FloatingStateType.Expanded
                    }
                )
            }) {
            Icon(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .rotate(rotate)
                    .size(32.dp)
                    .background(Color.Transparent),
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.todolistaddemogi),
                contentDescription = null,
                tint = NextButtonArrowTint
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun FloatingActionButtonMenus(
    onMultiFloatingStateChange: (FloatingStateType) -> Unit,
    onButtonClick: (String) -> Unit,
    focusRequester: FocusRequester,
) {
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(155.dp)
            .height(110.dp)
            .padding(bottom = 10.dp)
            .shadow(
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(20.dp),
                elevation = 5.dp,
                spotColor = Color(0xff9E9E9E),
                ambientColor = Color(0xffACACAC)
            )
            .background(Color.White)
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentSize()
        ) {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
            ) {
                Button(modifier = Modifier.size(width = 25.dp, height = 25.dp),
                    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color(0xffFFB4B4)),
                    onClick = {
                        onButtonClick("1")
                        onMultiFloatingStateChange(FloatingStateType.Collapsed)
                        focusRequester.requestFocus()
                    },
                    content = {})
                Button(modifier = Modifier.size(width = 25.dp, height = 25.dp),
                    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color(0xffFFDCA8)),
                    onClick = {
                        onButtonClick("2")
                        onMultiFloatingStateChange(FloatingStateType.Collapsed)
                        focusRequester.requestFocus()
                    },
                    content = {})
                Button(modifier = Modifier.size(width = 25.dp, height = 25.dp),
                    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color(0xffB1E0CF)),
                    onClick = {
                        onButtonClick("3")
                        onMultiFloatingStateChange(FloatingStateType.Collapsed)
                        focusRequester.requestFocus()
                    },
                    content = {})
            }

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 7.dp))

            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
            ) {
                Button(modifier = Modifier.size(width = 25.dp, height = 25.dp),
                    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color(0xffB7D7F5)),
                    onClick = {
                        onButtonClick("4")
                        onMultiFloatingStateChange(FloatingStateType.Collapsed)
                        focusRequester.requestFocus()
                    },
                    content = {})
                Button(modifier = Modifier.size(width = 25.dp, height = 25.dp),
                    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color(0xffFFB8EB)),
                    onClick = {
                        onButtonClick("5")
                        onMultiFloatingStateChange(FloatingStateType.Collapsed)
                        focusRequester.requestFocus()
                    },
                    content = {})
                Button(modifier = Modifier.size(width = 25.dp, height = 25.dp),
                    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color(0xffB6B1EC)),
                    onClick = {
                        onButtonClick("6")
                        onMultiFloatingStateChange(FloatingStateType.Collapsed)
                        focusRequester.requestFocus()
                    },
                    content = {})
            }
        }
    }
}
```